# Search in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a script that reads files from different directories; then I am using the file ID to search in the `csv` file. Here is the piece of code.

```
import os
import glob

searchfile = open("file.csv", "r")
train_file = open('train.csv','w')



listOfFiles = os.listdir("train")
for l in listOfFiles:
    dirList = glob.glob(('/train/%s/*.jpg') % (l))
    for d in dirList:
        id = d.split("/")
        id = id[-1].split(".")
        print id[0] # ID
        for line in searchfile:
            if id[0] in line: # search in csv file
                value= line.split(",") 
                value= value[1]+" "+ value[2] + "\n"
                train_file.write(id[0]+","+value) # write description
                break
searchfile.close()
train_file.close()
```

However, I am only able search couple of ID's from the `csv` file. Can someone point out my mistake. (please see comments for description)

**EDITED**

Instance of the text file.

```
192397335,carrello porta utensili 18x27 eh l 411 x p 572 x h 872 6 cassetti,,691.74,192397335.jpg
```

Comment: is `id` meant to be the filename, without extension?

Comment: yeah. Here I extracted that `id = d.split("/")
        id = id[-1].split(".")`

Comment: You can see the instance of the text file @asongtoruin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when you do `for line in searchfile:` you're looping over a generator. The file doesn't reset for every `id` - for example, if the first `id` you pass to it is in line 50, the next `id` will start checking at line 51.

Instead, you can read your file to a list and loop over the list instead:

```
import os
import glob

with open("file.csv", "r") as s:
    search_file = s.readlines()

train_file = open('train.csv', 'w')

list_of_files = os.listdir("train")
for l in list_of_files:
    dirList = glob.glob(('/train/%s/*.jpg') % (l))
    for d in dirList:
        fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(d))
        print fname[0] # ID
        for line in search_file:
            if fname[0] in line: # search in csv file
                value = line.split(",") 
                value = value[1]+" " + value[2] + "\n"
                train_file.write(fname[0]+","+value) # write description
                break

train_file.close()
```

I made a couple of other changes too - firstly, you shouldn't use the name `id` as it has meaning in Python - I picked `fname` instead to indicate the file name. Secondly, I canged your CamelCase names to lowercase, as is the convention. Finally, getting the file name and extension is neat and fairly consistent through a combination of `os.path.splitext` and `os.path.basename`.

Comment: Actually you want `os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(d))`. You may also simplify the search using `glob.glob('/train/*/*.jpg')`

Comment: yeah. Thank you. I was optimizing the code based on the recommendation. @asongtoruin

Comment: I believe, I asked a pretty valid question however I still don't positive vote. I never understood that part of stackoverflow @asongtoruin

Answer (score 1):

You need to browse of lines of searchfile for each id found, but as you open the file outside of the loop, you only read each line once in the whole loop.

You should either load the whole file in a list and iterate the list of lines inside the loop, or if searchfile is really large and would hardly fit in memory reopen the file inside the loop:

List version:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as searchfile:
    searchlines = searchfile.readlines()

train_file = open('train.csv','w')

listOfFiles = os.listdir("train")
for l in listOfFiles:
    dirList = glob.glob(('/train/%s/*.jpg') % (l))
    for d in dirList:
        id = d.split("/")
        id = id[-1].split(".")
        print id[0] # ID
        for line in searchlines:   # now a list so start at the beginning on each pass
            if id[0] in line: # search in csv file
                value= line.split(",") 
                value= value[1]+" "+ value[2] + "\n"
                train_file.write(id[0]+","+value) # write description
                break
train_file.close()
```

Re-open version

```
train_file = open('train.csv','w')

listOfFiles = os.listdir("train")
for l in listOfFiles:
    dirList = glob.glob(('/train/%s/*.jpg') % (l))
    for d in dirList:
        id = d.split("/")
        id = id[-1].split(".")
        print id[0] # ID
        searchfile = open("file.csv", "r")
        for line in searchfile:
            if id[0] in line: # search in csv file
                value= line.split(",") 
                value= value[1]+" "+ value[2] + "\n"
                train_file.write(id[0]+","+value) # write description
                break
        searchfile.close()
train_file.close()
```